# redirect to reffer page after login wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i'm using this code to redirect not logged users from a specific page to login page

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {

    if ( is_user_logged_in() || ! is_page() ) return;
  
    $restricted = array( 5049 ); // all your restricted pages
  
    if ( in_array( get_queried_object_id(), $restricted ) ) {
      wp_redirect( site_url( '/user-account' ) ); 
      exit();
      
}});
```

after login users are redirect to their account i want to change this to redirect them to previous page that they visited

Comment: As always on Stack Overflow, you need to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). For instance, what have you tried, what didn't work? What exactly are you stuck on? People generally appreciate it if you put in some effort rather than just "please fix my code".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` should hold the last visited page, if any.

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() || ! is_page() ) return;

$restricted = array( 5049 ); // all your restricted pages

if ( in_array( get_queried_object_id(), $restricted ) ) {
  $previous_url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ? : site_url( '/user-account' );
  wp_redirect( $previous_url); 
  exit();
  
}});
```

Comment: thank you for reply where should i add this code ? i m not good at coding

Comment: You can add the code to a plugin or child theme. I answered a similar question here [How to lock Wordpress front-end with login and password?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/256251/how-to-lock-wordpress-front-end-with-login-and-password). The section *Custom Plugin* of my answer has some references on where to start with creating a plugin.

Comment: You might use WordPress function wp_get_referer()

Comment: @kofeigen 
it didn't work with me because the login page of my website is generated by LMS plugin and is not a simple page so when I redirect to user-account it means that the user is redirected to their profile and not to a login page

Comment: @Mouna. Sorry if there was some confusion. My earlier comment was only intended to answer your question "*where should i add this code?*" That is why I directed your attention to the section *Custom Plugin*. But, I see you did not upvote or mark *IT goldman*'s answer as correct. Are you saying IT goldman's solution did not work?

Comment: Yes sorry the code IS working i juste dis not Ask the right question thank you all